# Error when converting CartPole Numpy arrays for PyTorch Tensors

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

Reposting this since I think my previous post rambled and did not get to the point right away.

I am studying Deep Q-Learning algorithms and I am following along with a Udemy instructor who is showing how to implement DQN to play in the CartPole V1 environment. I followed the instructor's lessons, but I get errors when I try to run the code. The instructor's code runs fine and the terminal prints periodic progress showing that the episodes are running. Maybe I have some typos, or maybe OpenAI's CartPole environment has changed since this Udemy video? I could use some pointers on trying to find out the issue.

I provide my code at the bottom of this post. I am currently troubleshooting in Jupyter Notebooks.

I am still learning about Tensors. I am trying to feed it an array, but I am confused about what CartPole V1 is giving me in terms of its state observation array. Cartpole seems to be returning observation states something like:

observation = (array([1,2,3,4]) , { } ) )

I think that I need to pass [1,2,3,4] to the PyTorch Tensor, but the empty brackets { } are being passed instead?

Here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2636\2152418340.py in <module>
    223 
    224             # Learn from the new action state reward tuple
--> 225             agent.learn(obs, action, reward, obs_)
    226 
    227             # Set the state to the new state so that we are choosing an action based on the new state in the next turn

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2636\2152418340.py in learn(self, state, action, reward, state_)
    149         # Deal with the nuance of the PyTorch framework. Convert state, action, reward, new state
    150         # from numpy arrays into PyTorch cuda tensors.
--> 151         states = T.tensor(state, dtype=T.float).to(self.Q.device)
    152         actions = T.tensor(action).to(self.Q.device)
    153         rewards = T.tensor(reward).to(self.Q.device)

ValueError: expected sequence of length 4 at dim 1 (got 0)
```

"obs" is the set of observations from the CartPole state environment.

"obs_" is the new state environment that is to be stepped to after performing an action.

To troubleshoot, I print the value of the obs, action, reward, and obs_ :

```
Shape of obs: (2,)
Shape of obs_: (4,)
Obs: (array([-0.02403044, -0.00757334,  0.02679377,  0.04566693], dtype=float32), {})
Action: 0
Reward: 1.0
```

My current/best guess about the cause of the error is that the tensor is looking at dim 1 which is the empty brackets { }.

Looks like obs[1] = { }

My guess is that I should be passing dim 0

obs[0] = array([-0.02403044, -0.00757334, 0.02679377, 0.04566693]

I tried this as a solution:

```
states = T.tensor(state[0], dtype=T.float).to(self.Q.device)
```

But then it seems to snowball into a bunch more errors. Not sure if I broke more things than I fixed by doing the above. The Udemy instructor didn't have anything like this happen:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2636\78475273.py in <module>
    223 
    224             # Learn from the new action state reward tuple
--> 225             agent.learn(obs, action, reward, obs_)
    226 
    227             # Set the state to the new state so that we are choosing an action based on the new state in the next turn

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2636\78475273.py in learn(self, state, action, reward, state_)
    162         # has the maximum Q-value.
    163         # Take the actions indices from this predicted Q-value tensor.
--> 164         q_pred = self.Q.forward(states)[actions]
    165 
    166         # Maximum action for the Agent's estimate of the value for the resulting states.

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2636\78475273.py in forward(self, state)
     64 
     65         # We pass the state through the first fully connected layer. The activation function is the Relu function.
---> 66         layer1 = F.relu(self.fc1(state))
     67 
     68         # We then pass Layer 1 through Layer 2, but we do not activate it. This calculates the weights for every

F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\linear.py in forward(self, input)
    112 
    113     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 114         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    115 
    116     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

RuntimeError: both arguments to matmul need to be at least 1D, but they are 0D and 2D
```

Any ideas are very helpful and appreciated.

Here is my entire code for context:

```
import gym
import numpy as np 
import torch.nn as nn 
import torch.nn.functional as F 
import torch.optim as optim 
import torch as T 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

class LinearDeepQNetwork(nn.Module): 
def init(self, lr, n_actions, input_dims): 
    super(LinearDeepQNetwork, self).init()
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(*input_dims, 128)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, n_actions)

    self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=lr)
    self.loss = nn.MSELoss()
    

    self.device = T.device('cuda:0' if T.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

    self.to(self.device)


def forward(self,state):
    layer1 = F.relu(self.fc1(state))
    actions = self.fc2(layer1)
    return actions

class Agent(): 
def init(self, input_dims, n_actions, lr, gamma=0.99, epsilon=1.0, eps_dec=1e-5, eps_min=0.01 ): 
# Constructor 
self.lr = lr 
self.input_dims = input_dims 
self.n_actions = n_actions 
self.gamma = gamma 
self.epsilon = epsilon 
self.eps_dec = eps_dec 
self.eps_min = eps_min 
self.action_space = [i for i in range(self.n_actions)] 
self.Q = LinearDeepQNetwork(self.lr, self.n_actions, self.input_dims)

def choose_action(self, observation):
    if np.random.random() > self.epsilon:
        state = T.tensor(observation, dtype=T.float).to(self.Q.device)
        actions = self.Q.forward(state)
        action = T.argmax(actions).item()

    else:
        action = np.random.choice(self.action_space)

    return action

def decrement_epsilon(self):
    self.epsilon = self.epsilon - self.eps_dec \
        if self.epsilon > self.eps_min else self.eps_min

def learn(self, state, action, reward, state_):
    self.Q.optimizer.zero_grad()
    states = T.tensor(state, dtype=T.float).to(self.Q.device)
    actions = T.tensor(action).to(self.Q.device)
    rewards = T.tensor(reward).to(self.Q.device)
    states_ = T.tensor(state_, dtype=T.float).to(self.Q.device)
    q_pred = self.Q.forward(states)[actions]
    q_next = self.Q.forward(states_).max()

    q_target = reward + self.gamma*q_next
    loss = self.Q.loss(q_target, q_pred).to(self.Q.device)

    # Back propagate and step the optimizer
    loss.backward()
    self.Q.optimizer.step()

    # Decrement epsilon
    self.decrement_epsilon()

#Next is the Main Loop

if name == 'main': 
env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')          
scores = [] 
eps_history = []

# Instantiate the agent.
agent = Agent(lr=0.0001, input_dims = env.observation_space.shape, n_actions = env.action_space.n)

# Iterate over n_games number of games
for i in range(n_games):
    
    # After every game, reset the score, done flag, and reset observations to its initial state
    score = 0
    done = False
    obs = env.reset()

    
    while not done:
        # Choose an action according to epsilon greedy selection using the current observation of the state as input
        action = agent.choose_action(obs)

        # Get new state, reward, done, and debug info from the environment after taking that action
        obs_, reward, done, info, _ = env.step(action)

        # increment the score by the reward
        score += reward

        # Learn from the new action state reward tuple
        agent.learn(obs, action, reward, obs_)

        # Set the state to the new state so that we are choosing an action based on the new state in the next turn
        obs = obs_
    
    # When the episode is done, append the score and the Agent's epsilon history for plotting purposes
    scores.append(score)
    eps_history.append(agent.epsilon)

    # After every 100 games, print debug information to the terminal and the mean scores over the previous 100 games
    if i % 100 == 0:
        avg_score = np.mean(scores[-100:])
        print('episode ', i, 'score %.lf avg score %.1f epsilon %.2f' % (score,avg_score, agent.epsilon))
```

Comment: While using ChatGPT, it helped me find that sometimes my code (or Cartpole, not sure which) passes a state variable to the Learn function as a tuple. The PyTorch tensors need an array as input, not a tuple. So the array in state[0] is needed. My suspicions were correct.

I needed to put what feels like a band-aid on the code. In the Learn function, I put an if isinstance(state, tuple), then state=state[0].

This worked and now my agent is playing with Cartpole. Maybe there is a more sophisticated solution, but this is what I found.